# SceneBuilder version 17.0.0 does not seem to work with JFoenix

Tags: scenebuilder, jfoenix, javafx-17

I updated Scenebuilder to version 17 and some controls from a third party library (JFoenix)do not seem to work.

I checked at least for JFXTextField and JFXSpinner.

To reproduce, simply install Scenebuilder 17.0.0 and add jfoenix library version 9.0.10.

When adding those 2 controls to a Pane, nothing happens,

Comment: how did you solve it ?

Comment: I did not for now I just remove those views from scenebuilder while I update my layout and put them back afterwards.